# Navigation bar is not responsive after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am new to web development.I met a problem when designing a scrolling navigation bar.

I used a bootstrap grid and jquery for this. If I don't scroll down and just resize the window, then everything is fine. The navigation bar is resized and in the center of the window. But after I scroll down, the size of navigation bar will be fixed. Its size won't change when I make window larger(it will be smaller if I make window smaller, but not centered). This may caused by setting width: nav.width() in js file, but I don't know how to fix it.

This is a new account so I don't have enough reputation to upload images. I will try to describe it using words. For example, at beginning, the parent of navigation bar is 1140px, the width of navigation bar is 100%, so its size is 1140px. If I resize the window, let us say the width of its parent is 720px, then the navigation bar width is also 720px. Then if I scroll down, the callback function in js will run, it will set the width to 720px, which is a fixed value, thus it won't be responsible any more. Now, if I resize window to make its parent back to 1140px, the width of navigation bar is 720px rather than 1140. So how to fix this?

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <header id="home" style="height:300px">
                    <nav id="nav-wrap">
                        <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                            <li class="current">
                                <a href="">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="smotthscroll">
                                <a href=""> About </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="smotthscroll">
                                <a href=""> Portfolio </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="smotthscroll">
                                <a href=""> Skills </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="smotthscroll">
                                <a href=""> Contact </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
 #nav-wrap {
    font: 22px 'opensans-bold', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

}


    ul#nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 2;
}

    ul#nav li {
    height: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
}

    ul#nav li a {
    color:white;
    padding: 8px 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}


    $(function() {
    var nav = $('#nav');
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var navWrap = $('#nav-wrap');
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if(shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                width: nav.width()
            });
            isFixed = true;
        }else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'static'
            });
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I changed the width: nav.width() to width: 100%, then it will match the body size rather its direct parent's width.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most likely comes from this part.

```
 var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if(shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                width: nav.width()
            });
            isFixed = true;
```

Try inversing or removing that part all together. It is saying if the navbar is not at the top, add a position of fixed to it as well as `nav.width()`, whatever you set that to equal - and this is precisely the opposite of what you want because it's what your problem is according to the question.

Comment: Thanks man, I know the problem is this part but I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: try removing that entire if statement along with it's variables, seems unnecessary for what you are trying to do and seems to be the problem causer here. May or may not fix the issue.